# nexus: Could not transfer artifact from/to nexus (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/)

Tags: java, maven, nexus, sonatype

I installed nexus repository manager 3 in my system. I configured maven2 proxy repository, when i tried to clean pom.xml file using 'mvn clean' command, I am getting below error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.sample.app:nexus-proxy-test >-------------------
[INFO] Building nexus-proxy-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.377 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-03T19:04:32+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to nexus (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/): Not authorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Error stack trace looks like below.

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.resourceExists (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:838)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.resourceExists (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$PeekTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.peek (WagonTransporter.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$PeekTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

**Reference**
https://help.sonatype.com/learning/repository-manager-3/first-time-installation-and-setup/lesson-2%3A-proxy-and-hosted-maven-repositories

Comment: The issue is here: `..t/): Not authorized -> [Help 1]`...

Comment: do i need to add any user details in settings.xml?

Comment: Obviously you have to otherwise you can't deploy artifacts to your repository manager ...apart from that I would be astonished if someone allows to do that from developers side only a CI solution should be able to do this...

Comment: Just a local setup...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is authorization issue. Open settings.xml file from folder where maven is installed and correct the user ID and password. It should solve your problem.

Jar is not getting downloaded because of incorrect passwords.

Comment: Or alternatively, enable anonymous access in Nexus Repo: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Anonymous+Access

Answer (score 0):

If you have made sure your settings.xml file has the correct user and password and it still doesn't work, make sure you are pointing to the right version of Maven. I had this error and it turned out my IDE was defaulting to a different version of Maven, one without a corrected settings.xml file.